# Adding unsubscribers into suppression list

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, contactbuilder, email-studio

If someone unsubscribes from marketing cloud we need add them to suppression list by query or other methods or it will automatically adds into suppression list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what unsubscribe mechanism you use. If you are using the ootb unsubscribe link, then once someone clicks it and unsubscribes, their status on the Publication List/All Subscribers List changes to `Unsubscribed` and they will be automatically excluded from all future sends using that particular list:

> Marketing Cloud unsubscribe links appear at the bottom of every email
> you send.
>
> A subscriber can choose to click the Manage Subscriptions link, which
> provides unsubscribe options. Or they can click One-Click Unsubscribe,
> which unsubscribes the subscriber from the list the send originated
> from. To unsubscribe from every list, the subscriber must click Manage
> Subscriptions and unsubscribe from every list.
>
> When a subscriber unsubscribes, they aren’t removed from a list or
> account. Their status is changed to Unsubscribed and a red icon
> appears next to their name on the list.

Make sure you understand each of the possible four unsubscribe types:

- List Unsubscribe
- Universal Unsubscribe
- Global Unsubscribe
- One-Click Header Unsubscribe

See here for more details: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_unsubscribes.htm&language=en_US

If you have a custom unsubscribe mechanism, it all depends on how it’s set up.